# Change XML padding attribute depending on display orientation

Tags: android, xml

in my XML layout I'm trying to set a different paddingTop on a LinearLayout depending on display orientation.

The code above is for portrait mode, but in landscape mode I would like, for example, `android:paddingTop="20dp"`

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

It is possible from XML or need I to manage it programmatically on screen orientation change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options when doing this using xml.  Either specify different layout files for portrait/landscape or use a single layout file and define different dimensions for portrait/landscape.

**Different Layout Files**

Using different layout is really only necessary if you have a significantly different layout in portrait/landscape.  It is harder to maintain different layouts as you app grows in size.  In your `res` folder you need to create two subfolders:

```
res/layout-port

res/layout-land
```

You would then create a file with the same name in each of these folders.  When the device is in portrait the file in `layout-port` is used and when in landscape the file in `layout-land` is used.

**Different Dimens Files**

The second option is to use one layout file but to define a dynamic dimension in it.  Firstly again you would need to create two folders in your `res` folder:

```
res/values-port
res/values-land
```

You then need to create a file called `dimens.xml` in each of those folders.  In the `values-port` folder you would set it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="main_screen_padding_top">60dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and in the `values-land` folder you would set it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="main_screen_padding_top">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then in your layout xml file you can reference that dimen value:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_screen_padding_top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView></TextView>
    <TextView></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And it will use the appropriate dimension depending on the orientation of the device.

For your purpose I suggest using the dimens method as it is generaly easier to maintain.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you